# I was attacking a city, so was a 3rd Civ, I captured it - now they are trespassing

Tags: civilization-6

I was attacking a city, so was a 3rd Civ, I captured it - now they have been trespassing for several turns.

Is this a bug? I am not at war with the 3rd civilization - though I have denounced them. Why aren't they being forced to move?

Comment: Do you have the Early Empire civic? Until you research that, you automatically have open borders with everyone.

Comment: I do it's well past that. I think it might be a bug? Perhaps trespassing is only checked in code as a unit enters foreign lands - not if a city is won by a third party?

Comment: Has it been a full turn since you conquered the city? It might not update the unit positions until that player's turn starts.

Comment: Like 10 turns...

Comment: Have you closed out your war with the other civ, the city isn't technically yours until the original civ cedes it to you.  It's only occupied up until that point, and doesn't necessarily follow the same border rules.

Comment: I wiped out the Civ whose city I captured. I am not at war with the third civ who is now camped out in my territory. That's an interesting point though - if I capture a city that is not ceded - a third party can enter my territory at will. Are you sure that's true?

Comment: There seems to be a number of bugs around unit movement. While I have not seen this particular one mentioned it is along the same lines so most likely another one.